# Interval date validation with sql query

Tags: php, mysql, date, post

Please help settle my code below :

```
$idbo   = $_POST['idbo']; $vebo = $_POST['vebo']; 
$title = $_POST['title']; $usbo = $_POST['usbo'];   
$date1 = $_POST['date1']; $date2 = $_POST['date2'];
$cek = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT idbo FROM boca 
       WHERE vebo='$vebo' BETWEEN date1 and date2"));
if ($cek > 0){
    echo "<script>window.alert('Date/Time and venue Already Booked...!!!')
    window.history.back()</script>";
```

My question is : 
- how to make sure booking between startdate(date1),enddate(date2) and room(vebo) is not conflict when range date1,date2 and room already booking...?

example :

- **Already Booking :**
- date1 = 2016-07-20 08:00:00
- date2 = 2016-07-20 09:00:00
- room = Room 1
- **New Booking :**
- date1 = 2016-07-20 08:30:00
- date2 = 2016-07-20 09:00:00
- room = Room 1

***- Then warning message show " Date/Time and Venue Already Booked "***

Answer (score 0):

Please check below query.
This query will check whether the booking time of user already booked with database record.

- User date1="2016-07-20 08:30:00" should not between all DB date1 and date2.
- User date2="2016-07-20 09:30:00" should not between all DB date1 and date2.

  - All DB date1 should not between user '2016-07-20 08:30:00' and '2016-07-20 09:30:00'.
  - All DB date2 should not between user '2016-07-20 08:30:00' and '2016-07-20 09:30:00'.

If user date1 and date2 will match above all conditions for the room then only allow to book for that room.

```
SELECT idbo FROM boca WHERE vebo='$vebo' ('2016-07-20 08:30:00' NOT BETWEEN date1 AND date2) and ('2016-07-20 09:00:00' NOT BETWEEN date1 AND date2) and (date1 NOT BETWEEN '2016-07-20 08:30:00' AND '2016-07-20 09:00:00') and (date2 NOT BETWEEN '2016-07-20 08:30:00' AND '2016-07-20 09:00:00')
```

Comment: Does it allow booking for already booked date time for the same room? Or it throws mysql error? Like syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict if for the same venue there is a record that starts before the end of the new one and ends after the start of the new one.

In other words it is not a conflict if one starts after the end of the other or one ends before the start of the other.

So this query returns all the conflicts:

```
SELECT idbo
FROM boca
WHERE vebo = :vebo AND date1 <= :date2 AND date2 >= :date1
```

You can add `LIMIT 1` if you are not interested to receive all conflicts.